# Abrir una tabla con un boton

Tags: php, html, sql

Hola lo que necesito es que se abra una tabla al yo presionar este boton:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que seria el de "Mas informacion" el problemas es que no se como mandar llamar al metodo onclick asi tengo mi codigo:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TOTAL WHERE NOMBRE='$buscar' OR CLAVE_UNICA_ALUMNO='$buscar' AND TOTAL<=4;";

try
{
$datos = $conexion->query($consulta);
$texto1 = "
<h2>TUTORIAS PRESENCIALES</h2>
<table class='table table-bordered'>
<thead>
  <th>
   VALOR
  </th>
  </thead>
<tbody>";
$datos = $conexion->query($consulta);
while ( $fila = $datos->fetch() ){
$texto1 = $texto1 ."<tr>
<td>".$fila[3]."</td>
</tr>";
  $cont = $cont + 1;
 }
 $texto1 = $texto1."
 </tbody>
 </table>";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
header("Location: index.html");
}
    if($cont!=0)
    {
      echo $texto1;
      $texto3 ="<input type='submit' onclick='btnMinformacion();'  class='btn btn-success' value='MAS INFORMACION'><br><br>";
      echo $texto3;
    }
else{
  echo "<h2>NO HAY</h2>";
}
```

Al final estara el boton veran que el metodo onclick se llama "btnMinformacaion();"

El problema es que no se como mandarlo a llamar

Estoy trabajando en Visual Studio Code y en esta parte uso lo que es php 
y no se como mandar llamar al metodo

Comment: ¿Sí puedes usar javascript en tu mismo template o archivo .php/html que estás usando?

Comment: No lo se, tengo unos archivos de javascript pero aparte no se si se pueda hacer dentro, como reviso eso?

Comment: Bueno es que tenía entendido que si usas VB no puedes ejecutar javascript en el mismo archivo, solo agrégale al final de tu archivo y antes de tu etiqueta de cierre </body> de tu código (si es que lo tienes si no agrégalo al final) un <script>alert(1);</script> en tu navegador o visor deberías de ver una alerta con el número 1, eso indica si eres capaz de ejecutar javascript

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu pregunta. ¿La tabla ya existe en `btnMinformacion()` o tienes que mandar a buscar los datos en el servidor (PHP)? Sería bueno que muestres lo que tienes en `btnMinformacion()`

Comment: Quiero que salga simplemente una tabla no se como hacer la tabla asi simple sin datos en "btnMinformacion" no tengo nada por que todavia no la creo

Comment: Fernando Torres si aparece el mensaje 1 supongo que si se puede escribir script ahora el detalle es como hago que aparesca una tabla al presionar el boton

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar contenido HTML lo más simple sería tener un contenedor adecuado en el DOM y usarlo para colocar allí tu contenido.

En este ejemplo tendremos un `div` cuyo `id` será `mas`. En el código JS crearemos una referencia a ese elemento y dentro de la función la usaremos para agregarle la tabla mediante `innerHTML`.

En este caso, por tu requerimiento, la tabla se crea a mano dentro de la función, pero podría venir de otro sitio, como de una consulta a la base de datos en el servidor, una API, etc.

```js
var divMas=document.getElementById("mas");
function btnMinformacion(){
var mTable=`<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The table body</td>
            <td>with two columns</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`;
divMas.innerHTML=mTable;

}
```

```css
table,
td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

thead,
tfoot {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type='submit' onclick='btnMinformacion();'  class='btn btn-success' value='MAS INFORMACION'><br><br>
<div id="mas"></div>
```